# Swiping between activities with swipe sticking to finger

Tags: android, gesture, swipe

I'm looking for a way to slide between my activities with the slide effect sticking to ones finger.

I'm not looking for an animation effect.

Currently I am using fling and onTouch classes. These work fine but I would like to create a "sticky" version for my library.

I have come across page viewer but it doesn't look like it will work between activities. Or maybe I'm not understanding it.

Is there any code out there with an example or video so you can see the effect is correct. Essentially its the Android Homepage effect i'm looking for. To be implemented between activities. Can't find anything practical on the web to use.

Thanks.

Comment: This can't really be done between activities - you might consider transitioning to fragments instead, if that will work for you.

Comment: Ok, that explains it. I'll have to look into fragments - i'm pretty new to Android dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Fragments as an implementation.  If you're targeting older OS releases, like gingerbread or froyo, you can use the compatibility package and the ViewPager elements to do pretty much exactly what you're describing.  Theres a few decent tutorials on it running around, [here's one of them](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/).  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks - came across this tut, but didn't understand the implementation. Looking into fragments now.